# Tailwind doesn't take the margin and padding to specific position

Tags: css, tailwind-css, create-react-app

I've been facing this issue with tailwind.  In some contexts it's impossibile to add  padding or margin to specific sides.
Note: This is a React application. So maybe I'm missing some configuration.

[image: Margin to all sides]

[image: Margin to specific side]

Comment: I bet 100 lines of code that you are creating tailwind class names dynamically. We need to see your code for that component.

Comment: Could you produce the code which didn't work properly, I could help you out

Comment: Can you create a snippet of your code and post it here?

Answer (score 1):

In your tailwind config you must make sure that the component is in a folder listed under the content glob rules below.  Hope that helps!

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./scr/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```